# QGeoCoordinate: No such file or directory, can't find .pro file

Tags: qml

I am trying to use QGeoCoordinate to make a set of MapPolyLines and update them.  However, when I include QGeoCoordinate in my .h file, I get the following output.

```
fatal error: QGeoCoordinate: No such file or directory
```

I tried to follow the steps in [QGeoCoordinate: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579560/qgeocoordinate-no-such-file-or-directory), however I do not seem to have a .pro file.  I have searched my system entirely with no luck.  What is this file, and should I have it?

Comment: Do you use   `cmake`? I already added the solution for cmake to have a post with all the possible options in one place

Comment: No I didn't see the cmake section at the bottom of that post.  I will give that a shot.  Thanks!